# If a manifold is contained in another manifold, is it a regular submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to wrap my head around regular submanifolds. There is an easy proposition that states that if M is regular submanifold of N, then M is itself a manifold (with the subspace topology). Is however the reverse correct? If $M \subset N   $ where N is a manifold and M manifold with the subspace topology, does that imply that it s a regular submanifold? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: No. That's why one distinguishes between immersed and regular submanifolds. Surely any book that introduces those concepts has an example of a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ that is an immersed submanifold that is not regular. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) for an example.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff It think that the question is more subtle than that, an immersed curve is not a manifold *for the subspace topology*

Comment: The only problem that I can see is about smoothness. A square is a $1$-submanifold of the plane, but it is not smoothly embedded. Does your notion of "subspace topology" carry smoothness information?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I answered the question in the title. :)

Comment: The book i m studying from is Loring Tu: An introduction to Manifolds and it provides no counterexamples, at least as far as i have seen, that s why i was asking for one. The whole point of the question is that M is not a random manifold, but a manifold equipped with the subspace topology, as Arnaud pointed out. As for the subspace topology i m not sure i completely understand what you mean that it carries smoothness information. Do you mean if it s a part of the definition?

Comment: The trouble with your question is that you are confusing two categories: The category of topological manifolds (where it makes sense to ask if a subset of a topological space equipped with the subspace topology is a topological manifold) and the smooth category where a smooth manifold is a topological space equipped with a collection of charts. As it stands, your question is not well-posed.